# How to pass FILE as a parameter to external js library from LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a requirement to add watermark to the uploaded image.

My HTML file is straight forward

```
<template>
    <div lwc:dom="manual"></div>
    <lightning-card title="Upload File Example" icon-name="custom:custom19">
        <lightning-file-upload
            label="Attach file"
            name="fileUploader"
            accept={acceptedFormats}
            record-id={recordId}
            onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
            multiple>
    </lightning-file-upload>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Here is my JS file which calls the watermark function from the watermark.js library. You can get the watermark.js file [here](https://github.com/brianium/watermarkjs/tree/master/dist)

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import wm from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/wm';
export default class Watermark extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    get acceptedFormats() {
        return ['.png','.jpg','.jpeg'];
    }

    handleUploadFinished(event){
        const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
        console.log('JSON '+JSON.stringify(uploadedFiles[0]));
        console.log('typeof '+ typeof uploadedFiles[0]);
        console.log('version 18 ');
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, wm)
        ]).then(() => {
            window.console.log('Files loaded.');
            watermark([uploadedFiles[0]])
            .image(text.lowerRight('watermark.js', '48px Josefin Slab', '#fff', 0.5))
            .then(function (img) {
                this.template.querySelector('lower-right').appendChild(img);
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            window.console.log("Error " + error);
        });
    }   
}
```

I am passing uploadedFiles[0] as a parameter to the watermark function thinking that it will consider it as a file but when I debug, it considers it just as an object.
And hence I receive this error
[image]

Can someone guide me how to do this? I am not sure if this can be achieved in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `lightning-file-upload` for this, it's not designed to handle reading files, only uploading to the provided `record-id`. Instead, create your own file upload component from the [template](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/file-selector/) and wire it up to expose files that are read. I wrote a version for work that works well, but I can't share it for obvious reasons, but it's very copy-paste, slight modifications, and then you should be able to use your script (it appears to be lwc compatible).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Do you recommend using LWC for this or Lightning component is a better approach?

Comment: @Angad LWC, definitely. It's very lean and easy to use.

Comment: @angad, if you want to read files you could also use lightning-input[type=file], the look and feel will be same as lightning-file-upload and it is already there so you don't need to build your own!

Comment: @PrashantKashyap my requirement is to watermark an image and I am unable to pass image as a parameter to external library. I end up getting CORS error (even after setting crossOrigin to anonymous) or the parameter I pass does not show up as an image in the javascript function.

Any other inputs on how to move ahead with this?

Comment: @sfdcfox it is a bit tricky to read files, convert them to images in Salesforce and external libraries don't seem to help. Can you suggest something?

Comment: @Angad You really don't need an external library for this, it should be pretty trivial to write your own. As an example, I wrote a custom file upload component (you could actually use lightning-input type="file" instead, as noted above), draw to a canvas, then get the data back out. Give me a little bit, I think I can write up an example for you.

Comment: @Angad I made you an [example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/hqacjvMGNYqquz1Tw3QI/src/app.js) script. On my computer, the buttons don't want to seem to work, but you can drag-and-drop the files onto the drop targets to select the images.

Comment: @sfdcfox IT WORKSS! I spent several nights on this :) 
I cannot thank you enough for this and I really appreciate you spending your time to write this up for me. Thanks a million.

Comment: @Angad You're welcome! Glad I could help.